# Smelting Titanium

Tags: terraria-mobile

I've beaten the Wall of Flesh and got the Pwnhammer. When I destroyed the 3 altars I got Orichalcum, Titanium, and Palladium. When I mine Titanium and try to smelt it, it says I need an Adamanite Forge but I don't have Adamantite in my world, so how do I smelt my Titanium?

This is on the mobile version.

Answer (score 4):

Titanium and Adamantite are equivalent to each other, both being tier 3 hardmode ores. As such you can craft a [Titanium Forge](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Titanium_Forge) instead, which functions in exactly the same way as an Adamantite Forge.

You can craft a Titanium Forge from 30 Titanium Ore and a Hellforge at a Mythril or Orichalcum Anvil.

This is *generally* true of most hardmode crafting recipies, but not all.

Comment: You should probably mention that you can make the titanium forge from titanium ore and a hellforge at an orichalcum anvil. I know that it's right there in the linked page, but it's nice to have it directly in the answer.